# MySQL adding columns from separate tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I'm new to SQL and am having trouble understanding how to use multiple tables at once.

I have a table like this:

```
Table1
| ID | Type |
| 1  | A    |
| 2  | B    |
| 3  | C    |
| 4  | D    |
```

And one like this:

```
Table2
| ID | Qty |
| 1  | 20  |
| 3  | 40  |
| 3  | 10  |
| 2  | 30  |
| 4  | 20  |
| 1  | 10  |
```

I want to display the summed quantities of each ID by sort them by type. I can sort them by ID by doing:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(Qty) FROM Table2 GROUP BY ID;
```

This works fine, I get what I should:

```
| ID | Qty |
| 1  | 30  |
| 2  | 30  |
| 3  | 50  |
| 4  | 20  |
```

So now I'm trying to group by Type and it's not working. I'm doing:

```
SELECT Type, SUM(Qty) FROM Table1, Table2 GROUP BY Type;
```

My output ends up being:

```
| Type | Qty |
| A    | 130 |
| B    | 130 |
| C    | 130 |
| D    | 130 |
```

So clearly it's just summing the whole column and displaying the result for each Type. Can someone explain how I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
SELECT t1.type, SUM(t2.qty) qty FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.type
```

You need an inner join between the tables. By using `FROM Table1, Table2` you're actually matching all values from table1 with all values from table2. That's why you get those numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.Type, SUM(T2.Qty) FROM Table1 T1, Table2 T2 where  T1.ID=T2.ID GROUP BY T1.Type;
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

```
select * from table1, table2
```

Is returning the cartesian product of the two tables. It will contain `count(table1) x count(table2)` rows, what is 4 x 6 = 24 rows in your case. This is not what you want.

There are two solutions:

1. Add a condition: `select * from table1, table2 where table1.id = table2.id`
2. Use a join: `select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id`

Joins are the preferred method and offer more possibilites.

[Learn more about joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)